# Dynamic menu from database CodeIgniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, dynamic, menu

I created a dynamic menu from database in codeigniter. But every time when I click to menu item and the window reload, it asks the database again for menu items. I need to ask only once when the user logs in to the application.

Do I have to create a session variable or there is another way to do that?
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something their prospective authors call Registry library. This library can be used for anything else because it is working on principle setting getting keys. One I could offer™ is [this one](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-registry/blob/master/Registry.php). So you would call DB for first time and set menu items as value for key of user session. That key would be globally available.